# how to view each element from the array only once in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native

so I have an array empty array which stores item with its image, text and key, I just want to view all items but if there is an item with the same key more than one I only want to view it once and not more than that.

this is my empty array

```
const { store } = useContext(CartContext);
```

I have a button that sends the item just like this

```
onPress={() => addToCart([item.pic, item.text, item.key])}
```

and this is where I view it all

```
<FlatList 
    data={store}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.listItem}>
          <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item[0]}   {item[1]}</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }}
  />
```

I believe I need some type of check to see if the same key appears more than once in the array but I cannot find the logic...

I appreciate any type of help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to check that the key exists in the array or not, because i assume that is the unique property of the object. You have multiple solutions, one is the following:

```
const addToCart = item => {
    const isItemInCart = state.find(cartItem => cartItem.key === item.key);
    if (!isItemInCart ) {
       setState(currentItems => [...currentItems, item]);
    }
}
```